# Recorrer array con Javascript en react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

llevo poco aprendiendo react native y tengo una duda. Estoy cargando desde una base de datos un listado de clientes, y quiero ponerlos en un select (Picker en react) que tenga cajón de búsqueda. El select con cajón de búsqueda me sirve perfectamente con esta estructura que pongo a continuación, pero no se montar esa estructura recorriendo los datos que me traigo de la base de datos:

Estructura que funciona:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
     {label: 'Spain', value: 'spain'},
     {label: 'Madrid', value: 'madrid', parent: 'spain'},
     {label: 'Barcelona', value: 'barcelona', parent: 'spain'},
     {label: 'Italy', value: 'italy'}
  ]);
```

Y dentro del return:

```
            <DropDownPicker
                open={open}
                searchable={true}          
                selectedValue={clienteSeleccion}
                onValueChange={(text) => { formik.setFieldValue("cliente", text); setSelectmodelos(text); setclienteSeleccionado(text); } }
                items={items}
                setOpen={setOpen}
                setValue={setValue}
                setItems={setItems}
                mode="BADGE"
                badgeDotColors={["#e76f51", "#00b4d8", "#e9c46a", "#e76f51", "#8ac926", "#00b4d8", "#e9c46a"]}
         />
```

Y aqui como me traigo los datos (Por si hace falta):

```
            useEffect(() => {
            fetch('https://estaurlesdeejemplo.es/api/data_clientes.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                token: auth.token,
            }),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseJson => {
                setDataSourceclientes(responseJson);
                console.log(responseJson);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
          }, []);
```

Y la estructura de los datos:

```
[{"cif": "Test", "id": "948", "nombre": "Test"}, {"cif": "Test2", "id": "949", "nombre": "Test2"}, {"cif": "Test3", "id": "950", "nombre": "Test3"}, {"cif": "Test3", "id": "951", "nombre": "Test3"}, {"cif": "Test3", "id": "952", "nombre": "Test3"}, {"cif": "Test3", "id": "953", "nombre": "Test3"}, {"cif": "Test3", "id": "954", "nombre": "Test3"}]
```

Comment: A ver si entiendo, tú quieres que el json que pusiste al final quede como la estructura que pusiste al principio??? cuál sería el `label` y cuál sería el `value` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

le he echado un visazo a la documentacion de DropDownPicker. Creo que lo mejor es seguir su ejemplo.

Deja el Componente tal como piden en la documentació (cuando funcione ya testeas con los cambios que veas)

```
   <DropDownPicker
        open={open}
        value={value}
        items={items}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        setValue={setValue}
        setItems={setItems}

        theme="DARK"
        multiple={true}
        mode="BADGE"
        badgeDotColors={["#e76f51", "#00b4d8", "#e9c46a", "#e76f51", "#8ac926", "#00b4d8", "#e9c46a"]}
      />
```

Entonces por lo que veo, necesitas 2 variables en el state. la Value i los Items (que los items iran enlazados por cada value)

Asi que puedes hacer algo así:

```
.then(responseJson => {
    const newItems = responseJson.map(obj => ({ label: obj.nombre, value: obj.nombre }));
    setItems(newItems);
    setValue(newItems.map(item => item.value)); // opcional
  })
```

lo de SetValue he visto que es opcional, por que funciona igual sin ello. **pero tiene que existir** la variable [value, setValue] aunque sea un arreglo vacío. De otra forma no funcionará el componente.